# Proposed tag delete: [custom]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

What the heck is up with the StackOverflow [custom](/questions/tagged/custom) tag?  There are over 2k posts with this tag, but this tag doesn't provide *any* useful grouping.  Topics range from Android, Doxygen, SharePoint, jQuery, you name it.  It would be virtually impossible to provide the tag's wiki with any meaningful text.  I've noticed the existence of the tag seems to bate users into "building a phrase" out of tags e.g. [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) [custom](/questions/tagged/custom) [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) [serializer](/questions/tagged/serializer) which doesn't seem like a healthy usage of the tag system ("custom XML serializer" is clearly title/body material).

I can't believe this tag has ever helped any StackOverflow user find content.  It just feels like noise in the tag list, as such I'm proposing the tag be removed from the system.

Comment: I've noticed that the community seems to favor more specific tags nowadays.  What exactly is wrong with "building a phrase", so long as none of the tags are "meta" tags?

Comment: building a phrase can give a user false sense of grouped categorization. I don't think encouraging that thinking helps the tagging system work the best that it can.  Tagging provides a very useful service with tags representing high specificity and a virtually useless system when hyper-generalities (like [custom]) are used.

Comment: Fair enough.  Is [wcf] [xml] [serializer] a legitimate phrase?

Comment: The custom tag, and it's ilk can be invaluable for searching. An [ordinary search for `+custom`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bcustom) maxes out the results -- useless.  A [Google site-search](http://www.google.com/?q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%2Bcustom) returns almost 2-million hits! ...   Yet, the custom tag is a more manageable 2043 hits and it's clear from [the "Highest Voted"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom?sort=votes) that *custom*-ness is an important aspect of most of those.

Comment: It's better, no doubt, as it describes the same thing, without the noise of [custom].  Personally, would probably first look for existing tags along the lines of [wcf-serialization] or [wcf]/[xml-serilization] before resorting to something like what you said.  I might even opt to leave the question at [wcf], not sure.

Comment: @Brock I see custom in the titles and bodies of those "Highest Voted", what makes adding a [custom] tag worthwhile to them?  I don't see that tag adding value to the question in terms of categorization or discoverability.

Comment: I already established that it's invaluable for searching.  Search sites would (and did) pay millions for a tagging system like that to cut through the fluff.  It couldn't be done cost-effectively for the web, but it WAS being done for SE (until someone burninated the useful tag).  Jeff doesn't get it, and SE suffers another loss of useful organization -- the absolute opposite of the "wisdom of the crowd".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]