# Is the "custom" tag okay for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

I just saw the [custom](/questions/tagged/custom) on Stack Overflow. This tag is used 4 question before.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660625/google-analytics-data-mismatch-between-custom-report-and-api
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657947/error-page-doent-work-in-websphere
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657373/change-name-of-wsdl-port-name-service-name-for-axis2-web-service
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656886/wcf-and-custom-wsdl-generator-reverse-proxy

It seems to me that there is no point using this tag. Should this tag be removed?

The tag has [previously been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101410/proposed-tag-delete-custom).

Comment: Wow, 20 followers for a tag with 4 questions.

Comment: @DanielFischer I assume those are from before it was [burninated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101410/proposed-tag-delete-custom).

Comment: Given that it is officially burninated, I've removed it from the questions it appeared on (and did my best to improve each of them). The tag should probably be blacklisted, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see a bad tag on a question, just edit it out. When the volume is this small, there's no real need to ask about it.