# Burninate and blacklist "custom" tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-block-request

As seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101410/proposed-tag-delete-custom), there was already an effort to burninate [custom](/questions/tagged/custom). However, there are now still questions with that tag, although the tag wiki asks users to not post with it. I think that we should burninate and blacklist it, as it appears to be an issue that has not been resolved.

Comment: I've just removed the tag from the four questions that were using it - and three of those questions need to be closed and/or deleted.

Comment: Sorry, this one is on my list of **200** tags I try to keep dead daily, but I'm on vacation this weekend and can't be as on top of it as I usually am. Unfortunately, there has been one and only one tag blacklist in the past two years.

Comment: @Charles I don't really understand why you need to go through all of the work to remove the tag from questions if the tag can be blacklisted instead. It seems like an overly long workaround for an easy solution. Can you explain why blacklisting would be a worse idea than cleaning up the tag so frequently? Thanks.

Comment: @BlueIce, it's not that blacklisting is a bad idea, it's that it requires developer intervention.  It's not something that the community can vote for, nor is it something that diamond mods can do.  SE, Inc has blatantly ignored / silently declined **every** blacklist request out of `[google]` for **in excess of two years**.  There are [far more frequently recurring tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139869/135887) that also could use blacklisting.  I think I nuke `[server]` and `[access]` twice a week.  This is why I have my list of 200 tags, growing at about 10-20 a month...